# Make git pull --rebase preserve merge commits

Tags: git, version-control

`git pull --rebase` removes unpushed merge commits. Is there a way to make it preserve them?

Say my history looks like—

```
A
| \ 
B  H
|  |
C  G
|  |
D  F
| /
E
```

(`A` being the merge commit.)

After a `git pull --rebase` it becomes—

```
H
|
G
|
F
|
X
|
B
|
C
|
D
|
E
```

(`X` being the new commits `git pull --rebase` inserted into my history.)—`A` is removed.

I know you can use `git rebase --preserve-merges` to preserve them with `git rebase`, but I don't see a way to preserve them with `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: You mean you want to keep the structure of the revision graph? (Otherwise, I'm not sure what that `A` is supposed to be.)

Comment: Yes—`A` is just the merge commit, "Merge branch *foo* into *bar*"

Comment: git 1.8.5 will introduce a neat way to preserve merge on `pull --rebase`: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18756102/6309)

Comment: I do not get, why this rebases the local history even with no remote changes at all aka I already had everything but wanted to be sure. Ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can split your `pull` in a `fetch` and a `rebase`

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin master --preserve-merges
```

Comment: For the `git-fetch(1)` command, more recent versions of Git actually require this syntax: `git fetch origin master`.

Comment: Use --rebase-merges, (--preserve-merges is deprecated)

Answer (score 36):

Update: As I presented in "[What exactly does Git's "`rebase --preserve-merges`" do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)", since Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), you would prefer the [new option `--rebase-merges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309) to the legacy one `--preserve-merge`

Since then:

- Git 2.22, Q2 2019, actually [deprecates `--preserve-merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa1b86e45743fd5895c33adcd3769782e608bb40), and
- Git 2.25, Q1 2020, [stops advertising it in the "git rebase --help" output](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c51181ffb178a6581ecb471091cbd2d0c48f165).

So:

```
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges origin/master 
# or
git config pull.rebase merges
git rebase --interactive origin/master (would use rebase-merges)
```

---

Original answer 2013:

Or (for the [upcoming git 1.8.5 Q4 2013](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a194eaddca201163aa756faccd519f056bd3c35e/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L66-L68), now delivered in git 1.8.5, 2013-11-27):

> "`git pull --rebase`" always chose to do the bog-standard flattening rebase.
> You can tell it to run "`rebase --preserve-merges`" by setting "`pull.rebase`" configuration to "`preserve`".

So a simple config will be enough to make sure your `pull --rebase` does preserve merge:

```
git config pull.rebase preserve
```

---

See [commit 66713ef3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66713ef3b00933755cdeff1ae823dda7b5843640) for more (thanks to [Stephen Haberman](https://github.com/stephenh)):

### pull: allow pull to preserve merges when rebasing

> If a user is working on master, and has merged in their feature branch, but now has to "`git pull`" because master moved, with `pull.rebase` their feature branch will be flattened into master.
>
> This is because "`git pull`" currently does not know about rebase's preserve merges flag, which would avoid this behavior, as it would instead replay just the merge commit of the feature branch onto the new master, and not replay each individual commit in the feature branch.
>
> Add a `--rebase=preserve` option, which will pass along `--preserve-merges` to rebase.
>
> Also add '`preserve`' to the allowed values for the `pull.rebase` config setting.

Comment: For those that work with lots of repositories make it work everywhere with: `git config --global pull.rebase preserve`

Answer (score 9):

Simply:

```
git pull --rebase=preserve
```

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---rebasefalsetruepreserveinteractive):

> When set to preserve, rebase with the `--preserve-merges` option passed to `git rebase` so that locally created merge commits will not be flattened.

Comment: Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---rebasefalsetruepreserveinteractive

Answer (score 0):

Since [git v2.22.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.22.0#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--p), `--preserve-merges` option has been deprecated in favor of `--rebase-merges` (to be used in combination with [`--interactive` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.22.0#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i)) to reapply commits on top of another base tip with `git-rebase`:

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges origin/master
```