# How do I compress multiple merges into a single merge?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a topic branch that looks like this. (the branch topic currently points at 'a0a0')

- a0a0 Merge branch 'Master' into topic
- b1b1 Merge Branch 'Master' into topic
- c2c2 Merge commit 'something from master' into topic
- d3d3 Merge Branch 'Master' into topic
- e4e4 Merge Branch 'Master' into topic
- f5f5 Merge Branch 'Master' into topic
- 6666 an actual commit
- [lots of history on the topic branch]
- 9999 original divergence point

How do I turn a0-f5 into a single merge commit?

I've tried: `git rebase -i f5f5` with the intention of telling it to `squash` those 5 commits, but instead it just gave every commit on the master branch between f5f5 and a0a0. So I turned all but the first and last from `pick` into `squash`, but that went crazy and rebased every single commit from master into a giant commit in place of all the merges, losing the fact that it was a 'merge'. That isn't what I expected!

I can do:

```
  $ git reset 6666
  $ git merge Master
```

but that requires me to re-do any merge commits.

So how do I compress those different merges into a single merge commit, that knows it's a merge, and also retains all the merge-conflict stuff?

Comment: A `git rebase -p -i` (`-p` standing for "preserve merge") is supposed to do that... but I have some doubt: see comments in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12967782/6309

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try at some point, though I had to wait ages as it applied hundreds of patches, occasionally tripping up and requiring my input (never actually a conflict, I would just have to git add -u, git rebase --continue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it:

```
git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -p f5f5 -p Master -m "Merge hurricane" a0a0:)
```

To understand how it works, first remember that there is absolutely nothing magical about a merge commit. It can be hard to create, but once created, it's embarrassingly easy to recreate **exactly**. This is because git doesn't record changesets, it records entire trees. Tools like `git show` display commits as diffs, and merge commits as very fancy diffs, but in reality a commit is the pointer to a full-fledged tree. Squashing some commits is a simple matter of recreating a new commit that contains the same tree, giving it a different parent and commit message.

The plumbing command `git commit-tree` does this last part. Given a parent commit (`f5f5`), a commit message, and a tree ID (easily referenced with `COMMIT:`), it creates a new commit that contains the specified tree. If the commit has a single parent, it will be a regular commit. If it has multiple parents, it will be a merge commit. Once the squashed merge commit is created, what remains is to point the current branch to the new commit with `git reset --hard`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and was trying to do using the porcelain (except I used 6666 rather than f5f5, same thing). Thanks :) Note: I had to update a computer from the ancient 1.7.4 for this to work. Not sure which version it was added in, other than 'a year ago'. https://github.com/msysgit/git/commit/79a9312cc99f9c2f2949e1211c708896e6037f64.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done using porcelain. Possibly one could `git reset --hard 6666`, then `git merge -s ours Master` to create a dummy merge without conflicts, then `git checkout a0a0 -- .` at top-level to copy `a0a0`'s tree to the index, and finally `git commit --amend` to create the desired commit. Plumbing-free, but I find it easier to remember and reason about the variant that makes use of `git commit-tree`.

Comment: Answer is coming in handy once again. I've taken to calling them Merge Hurricanes.

Comment: Glad to be of service, but if you're using this hack *too* often, it might be time to rethink your git workflow. :)

Comment: It's a private topic branch that I need to keep updated. It's very quite old and full of commits that I don't want to be suddenly made context-less by rebasing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git checkout 6666 -b master_squashed
git merge --squash master
git commit -m 'My new feature'
git checkout master
git merge master_squashed
```

Comment: This raises all of the merge conflicts already resolved in a0,b1 etc. I'd prefer not to do that, otherwise I would just go with the `git reset 6666 && git merge master` method.

Comment: Hmmm -- well that's all I have for that one.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer:

```
git diff 6666 f5f5 > patch-f5f5.patch
git checkout 6666
git apply patch-f5f5.patch
```

As you prefer, you may also use `git apply --cached` or `git apply --index` which allow you to make further modification before commit.