# How to preserve merge commits automatically while using git pull --rebase?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase

I want to keep the branch information of merged branches, so I have set up `branch.master.mergeoptions=--no-ff`. This way, a merge commit is always generated even when it could be fast-forwarded.

A side effect however, is that a merge commit is created when doing a `git pull` (more specifically: Update in IntelliJ or Eclipse). To prevent a log full of `Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'`, I also set `branch.master.rebase=true` which will fast-forward the `master` to `origin/master` when pulling it.

This setup has another side effect: when I merge a branch to `master` and after that I `git pull` because I forgot to do that before the merge, my branch information is lost: the feature branch is flattened in `master`.

The command `git pull --rebase=preserve` is exactly what I need: it will rebase `master`, then apply the merge of the branch again. But I need this to be done automatically, since most of these commands are executed by Eclipse or Intellij. I want `git pull` actually perform a `git pull --rebase=preserve`

There's a [config setting `pull.rebase=preserve`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756102/5094336) which should do just that, but even after I set this config, `git pull` will do just a `git pull --rebase` and not the expected `git pull --rebase=preserve`, while I'm currently using git version 2.12.2 which is expected to contain that feature.

So how can I make sure that when I do a `git pull` on my master, that it will preserve my merge commits even when I didn't update my master before the merge?

Comment: I actually don't follow you, but why not just do everything from the command line, possibly using a script, where you have more control?

Comment: Not everyone in the company is as experienced and freak out on using the command line. That's why I need a way to make these things work by using default Eclipse or IntelliJ updates - in which you have limited or no control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting `branch.master.rebase=true` is actually overriding the default `pull.rebase=preserve`.

The solution is to execute the command
`git config branch.master.rebase merges`
so that the config setting is now `branch.master.rebase=merges`. This will preserve the merge commits automatically when doing a `git pull`