# git rebase origin/develop vs git rebase develop

Tags: git, git-rebase

Let's assume the current branch is MyFeatureX. And the local `develop` branch is up-to-date with origin. Would the two statements below be equivalent? 
What is the recommended syntax?

```
git rebase origin/develop 
git rebase develop
```

Please note: This *is not* the same question as [git rebase origin vs.git rebase origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963597/git-rebase-origin-vs-git-rebase-origin-master)

Comment: This appears to be an identical question to the one you linked. The second answer down is probably the most helpful for your case.

Comment: How come they are similar? I have no branch named `origin`. In my setting, `origin` is an alias to mean a remote repository (seen by `git remote -v`). I my question here `develop` is a local branch which is tracking the `origin/develop` branch on remote.

Comment: oh, you're right, that question is an unusual use case and I misread it as this case. although it's basically the same under the hood

Comment: I just commented on that other question, but this is yet another place Git is overly tricky / sneaky. Typically `origin` is the *name of a remote* (hence short for a URL), but in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) notation, `origin` is short for `origin/HEAD`, which is what Git calls a *symbolic reference*, i.e., a name for yet another name (!).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your local branch `develop` **tracks** `origin/develop` and they might not always have the same commits in them.

```
$ cat ~/.git/config

[remote "origin"]
    url = git@something.com/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This means we have a "remote" (a repository living somewhere else) arbitrarily named "origin".

Your local `develop` branch is tracking the branch from that remote repository, and there's a local reference to that data called `origin/develop`. For the most part, we consider these two things to always contain the same commits. However, you need to explicitly update your local `develop` branch to get the latest data from origin. This is mostly commonly done with a pull:

```
$ git status
    on branch develop
$ git pull
    ...pulls latest changes from origin
```

However, a `git pull` actually does two steps, a `fetch` and a `merge`. The first step it does under the hood is fetch all the latest commits from origin, which you can do with

```
git fetch origin
```

**This will update the branch `origin/develop`, but not your local branch `develop`.**

The newest commits are hidden "behind the scenes" in your local .git directory, which you can reference from the branch named "origin/develop".

After a fetch, to actually make your local branch `origin`, you would have to do `git merge origin/develop`. This technically isn't a merge, it will be a "fast forward," meaning git is smart enough to make your local `origin` branch match `origin/develop` without actually merging anything. For this reason and others, merges freak me out in git.

So if you rebase off of `develop`, there's  a chance it will be out of date (older) than `origin/develop`.

I personally do this workflow before rebasing:

```
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/branchname
```

This means that I can pull all data down without having to think too much about what branch I'm on, and rebase off the latest code from the remote repository. Later, on the `develop` branch, a simple `git pull` will make sure you're up to date.

Comment: Nice academic explanation about the synchronization mechanism between local and remote branches. I am relieved to have you guys confirm that `git rebase origin/develop` is equivalent to `git rebase develop`. Providing I must have taken care to keep them in sync. I'll follow your advice, using the `origin/develop` reference. May be this is obvious so that the [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) doesn't mention the details about how to address a "baseBranch". But for a rebase novice, this was quite confusing.

Answer (score 4):

If `develop` points to the same commit as `origin/develop` then the two commands are exactly the same. I would tend to use `origin/develop` in case I had forgotten to update my local `develop` (assuming this branch is eventually going to be pushed to `origin/develop`).

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my other (long) answer to your previous question [Why is "rebase --onto ABC" different than "rebase ABC"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42616979/1256452), both of these commands turn off `--fork-point` mode, so—provided that both `develop` and `origin/develop` resolve to the same commit hash, as they do in your question premise—the two commands will do the same thing.

Omitting the `<upstream>` argument turns `--fork-point` on by default, and the reflog for the branch's configured upstream may have a lot of data in it.  In this case, they may act quite differently.  By adding an explicit `--no-fork-point`, you can prevent `git merge-base --fork-point` from dropping upstream-removed commits.

Comment: super cool, especially for your answer to my other `rebase --onto` question. Please give me sometime to absorb that `--fork-point` business.