# why I need to use origin/master instead of master in rebase

Tags: git

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.1
$ git branch -avv
* master                017Fcc0 [origin/master] xxxx
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
```

My understand is that the origin/master is the remote master branch path name and master is my local branch name. I need to combine multiple my local commits into one and then submit it to remote server with latest time stamp. The following three steps serve me well but I don't understand why I need to use **origin/master** instead of **master**.

```
   a) git rebase --ignore-date origin/master
   b) git rebase -i origin/master
   c) git push origin master:master
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["git rebase origin" vs."git rebase origin/master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963597/git-rebase-origin-vs-git-rebase-origin-master)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to use origin/master in order to combine multiple commits into one. But it is a good way to do it in order to avoid having to overwrite history on the origin.

For instance, if you history looks like:

```
5abcde Commit 5 [master] [HEAD]
4abcde Commit 4
3abcde Commit 3
2abcde Commit 2 [origin/master]
1abcde Commit 1
```

And your master points to `5abcde` and origin/master points to `3abcde`.
If you run `git rebase master` you rebase your current position (which is probably already master) on the same position, effectively doing nothing.

Running `git rebase origin/master` or `git rebase 2abcde` would apply the commits that you have (3,4,5) after the commit (2) - and if you specify the flag `-i` gives you the option to squash/fixup/skip/reword/drop/pick the commits 3,4,5 respectively.

The Git documentation is imho actually very good on explaining on how rebase works: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Perhaps it helps to read up a bit more on how Git works with regards to remotes: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes